# Angularjs: Hide navbar for urls containing dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I got a strange situation in my angularjs application. I've a view like below

**index.html**

```
<body>
<nav ng-include="'/views/partials/nav_bar.html'" ng-if='location.path() !== "/" && location.path() !==  "/signin" && location.path() !== "/register" && location.path() !==  "/forgot_password" && location.path() !== "/update_password"  && location.path() !== "{{page_id}}"  '></nav>

 <div data-ng-view>

 </div>
</body>
```

You can see that it does not contain any controller initialization (because all other pages with controller specification will be rendered inside `data-ng-view`) . But i want to hide my navbar for specific pages . which i got working with above `ng-include` tag (pretty ugly condition - I accept) .But then i've a page with dynamic parameter say `'search/:id'` now `location.path()` fails to work . My issue is that I want to hide navbar for some static#dynamic urls .

I'm using `ng-token-auth` for front end verification .

Comment: Why not create a base controller? That `ng-if` is really badly placed in my opinion. Imagine if you grow to 100 pages...that is not scalable whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the condition into a controller, and then you can a much cleaner job at determining if the nav should be visible.

Here's a working example.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('BaseController', function($scope, $location) {
  var excludeUrls = ["/signin", "/register", "/forgot_password", "/update_password"];
  $scope.path = '/someUrl';
  $scope.navbarIsVisible = function() {
    var path = $scope.path; //this would be $location.path() normally, but for this example we are allowing it to be manually entered
    if (path === '/') {
      return false;
    }

    //anytime the url contains any variation of the exclude urls, hide the navbar
    for (var i = 0; i < excludeUrls.length; i++) {
      var excludeUrl = excludeUrls[i];

      //if the path starts with the given url, hide the navbar
      if (path.indexOf(excludeUrl) === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BaseController">
  <nav ng-if='navbarIsVisible()'>I am the navbar and I am visible</nav>
  Enter the url to see if the navbar should be visible:
  <input type="text" ng-model="path" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i agree with you that moving logic to controller will make things beautiful . but can i initiate a controller in index.html while other controller will be linked with templates while rendering them inside `ng-view`

Comment: i don't know why but the value `navbarIsVisible()` is not set again until refresh the page

Comment: You can have nested controllers, so yes, you can have a controller in index.html, and then a different controller underneath that inside the ng-view.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "navbarIsVisible() is not set again until refresh the page"? It should be getting called during each digest cycle. In my example, anytime you change the text box value, the navbar will recalculate whether it is visible or not. Are you saying that this is not happening in your code?